# Camera movies will not play

Tags: video, playback

I have recoded video footage on my Fuji X-S1 camera, which plays back fine on the actual camera, but when transferred to my computer, running Ubuntu 12.04, the movie files will not play. Photographs taken on the same camera view fine, it is just the movies. Can anyone assist in this please?

Comment: What's the file extension for the movies? Mp4? avi? Also what version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: What program do you use to play them? In my experience VLC plays everything

Comment: Some more information of the video file format would be helpful. Could you please copy a movie to your pc and add the outcome of `file moviename` and `avprobe moviename` to your question`?

Comment: The file extension is .mov  I am still on v12.04, awaiting an upgrade.

Comment: Having now installed VLC, I can say that it does indeed play the movies - providing I have not used the zoom function whilst recording. On the files where I used zoom, although they play perfectly ok on the camera playback, on the computer the picture jumps erratically, missing bits out, whenever zoom was used.

Answer (score 3):

As `vlc` has built-in decoders I would recommend to install it instead of installing by hand the missing plugins for `Totem` (the default media player).

from a terminal: `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Using the Software Center, just search for `vlc` and click on install

Answer (score 2):

Fujifilm X-S1 can save video files in H.264 MOV format. The default media player Totem should tell you which codec is missing and try to install it (package `x264`).

If you use another media player or Totem is not able to find out which codec is missing, you can install the package [`ubuntu-restricted-extras`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-restricted-extras) package:

[image: Install via the software center]

Afterwards you should be able to play those video files.

Comment: Thank you for that. I shall try it later and report back. Cheers.